# Automatically enter SSH password without using SSH Key, 'expect', 'sshpass' or Python

Tags: shell-script, ssh, powerpc, yocto

I have small device that starts up a tiny VM of PowerPC linux that I need to SSH into from a script on a tiny version of Yocto linux. The PowerPC VM SSH passwords stay the same, but it resets *most* of its core files, including regenerating its ssh keys, each restart.

The Yocto linux installation doesn't have the 'expect' command, nor can it install 'sshpass'. It has an extremely limited version of Python.

I'd like to be able to complete the password requirement from a basic 'ssh' prompt using only a shell script. Is this possible?

Comment: To be clear: regenerating keys on SSH server has no effect on client authentication; do you mean the re-started server (also) removes or clears ~user/.ssh/authorized_keys ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want a script that will send a password to the remote when logging in via ssh, here's some very minimal python code that should not need any extra libraries and so on. Obviously, it is just an example of what is possible using just os forkpty execlp read write.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# simplest builtin python pseudo-tty for ssh password. meuh 
# http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276385/119298
import os
def run(cmd,*args):
    pid, fd = os.forkpty()
    if pid==0: # child
        os.execlp(cmd,*args)
    while True:
        data = os.read(fd,1024)
        print data
        if "password:" in data:    # ssh prompt
            os.write(fd,"mypassword\n")
        elif data.endswith("$ "):  # bash prompt for input
            os.write(fd,"echo hello\n")
            os.write(fd,"echo bye\n")
            os.write(fd,"exit\n")

run("ssh", "ssh", "user@remote")
```

Note, you need to give "ssh" twice, once for argv[0].

Answer (score 0):

Hey Thank you meuh for your tip !
I need to do a loop to send commands on differents devices, and I custom your code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# simplest builtin python pseudo-tty for ssh password. meuh 
# http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276385/119298

import os
import subprocess
import getpass

addresses = open('IP_addresses.txt', 'r')
lines = addresses.readlines()

update_log = open('Update_Log.txt', 'w')
update_log.close()

password = getpass.getpass(prompt='Password: ', stream=None)

def ssh_connect():
        global count
        count = 0

        for line in lines:
                count += 1
                print line.strip()
                x = line.strip()
                x = x.split(',')

                def run(cmd,*args):
                        pid, fd = os.forkpty()
                        if pid==0: # child
                                os.execlp(cmd,*args)
                        while True:
                                data = os.read(fd,1024)
                                print data
                                if "Password:" in data:    # ssh prompt
                                        os.write(fd,password)
                                        os.write(fd,"\n")
                                elif data.endswith("#"):  # bash prompt for input
                                        os.write(fd,"terminal l 0\n")
                                        os.write(fd,"show version\n")
                                        os.write(fd,"exit\n")
                                        if "closed." in data:  # connection closed for input
                                                break
                run("ssh", "ssh", '%s@%s' %(x[0], x[1]))

                if not line:
                        break
                print("Line{}: {}".format(count, line.strip()))

addresses.close()
print ssh_connect()
```

It doesn't work as I wanted because my command "Exit" block the loop.. I'll continue to look a solution.

Comment: If you need clarification on an answer, please don't post this as an answer to the original question. The answer section is only intended for solutions to the original problem. Instead, post a comment under the answer where you need further explanation.